# How to capture stream from dvb-s card on windows?

Tags: dvb

I need to programmatically capture video directly from a dvb-s/s2 (NOT DVB-T) pci card including accessing the card and recording the video into a file.  I'm hoping to turn this into a command line program and .NET or Python would be preferable.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I've edited your question in an effort to more clearly state your intent.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Capture a DVB-T Stream to a movie-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264994/capture-a-dvb-t-stream-to-a-movie-file)

Comment: i'm searching for DVB-S not DVB-T

Answer (score 0):

you can use nextpvr with it's http-based apis

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).